# OpenSSL license questions

Tags: copyright

I want to make use of the OpenSSL library in a project, but I do not understand its license well, Then I would like to know:

- Does the OpenSSL license have copyleft?
- Should I give some attribution and if so how?

Answer (score 3):

The handwritten license is indeed confusing. Based on this [discussion](https://lwn.net/Articles/653135/), it is not copyleft. Points 1, 2, 3, and 6 of the OpenSSL License describe how to give attribution:

> 1. Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer.
> 2. Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in the documentation and/or other materials provided with the distribution.
> 3. All advertising materials mentioning features or use of this software must display the following acknowledgment: "This product includes software developed by the OpenSSL Project for use in the OpenSSL Toolkit. (http://www.openssl.org/)"

...

> 6. Redistributions of any form whatsoever must retain the following acknowledgment: "This product includes software developed by the OpenSSL Project for use in the OpenSSL Toolkit (http://www.openssl.org/)"

On the bright side, OpenSSL is currently in the [process of being relicensed under the Apache License 2.0](https://www.openssl.org/blog/blog/2017/03/22/license/), which is not copyleft and requires only the preservation of the copyright notice.